# Vote count average

Tags: discussion, voting

How many votes can be done within hour? Or are there any voting average time?

Yesterday **30** reputation points was gone for **Voting corrected**([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)), and I asked my friend. He says he also had that experience with **60** reputation points.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: You can use up to 40 votes per day. After that you will not be able to vote any more until that day has past. If you vote fast enough you can fit all of those 40 within 1 hour. So, to answer your first question: 40.

Comment: i read it. but there is no clue how may votes can be done within how much of time period.

Comment: @Ivar does this occur only i do this to one person.

Comment: @SandunChathuranga Did you read BoltClock's answer?

Comment: no. can you drop me a link?

Comment: @SandunChathuranga [I sure can](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321768/479156), but it would be easier to scroll down...

Comment: oops :D .i did see that. thank you @Ivar.

Comment: So the fact you ask "I am voting on one person"..... kinda shows you're probably voting for the wrong reasons...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't a matter of how many votes can be cast within a certain time frame. This is a matter of how you are voting, and whom you are voting on.

You've read the article linked to by the "learn more" text, and you probably understand what triggered the vote reversal. If you, your friend, or people you know were responsible for any of these votes (whether between yourselves or to other people), I suggest not focusing on how to avoid getting your votes reversed. Instead, if you treat every post equally regardless of the user who posted it, rather than reserving your votes only for posts contributed by specific people or visiting someone's profile and upvoting their content in bulk, you will have nothing to worry about.

In some cases, a moderator will have contacted the users involved regarding our voting policies, but no such email appears to have been sent to you — this was an action by the system alone and no moderator was involved. As you have posted on meta, I'm offering you the same advice in hopes you will follow it. We want to keep the site fair for everyone and in doing so we need to discourage targeted voting towards specific users.